# 0.0625 hertz oscillation?

Tags: electromagnetism, oscillators, wavelength

Today my son and I were measuring the voltage on a fairly long wire with a multimeter. This wire was connected to an old, unused, satellite dish pointing towards the sky. The ends of the cable were not connected to anything. We attached a multimeter and began measuring on the lowest (most sensitive) setting. This multimeter is not of any particular quality, simply your average device picked up at the hardware store.

As we sat watching the readings, there appeared to be a slow but VERY consistent oscillation. The meter would range from +001.2mv to -001.2mv with approximately 16 seconds between peaks.

It isn't like I was using a high end oscilloscope or something. I know my multimeter could be imprecise for such things. I guess. Could it? We are studying and learning about things like radio waves, electromagnetism, etc. So maybe I completely misunderstand. But, my belief is that this is a sine wave. The slow ticking of the voltage between the two values was *very* consistent and if I understand correctly this appears to have been somewhere around a 0.0625hz oscillation. Am I confused?

If this is the case I am guessing we were picking up some random background noise from ... what? As I understand it the earth itself oscillates at approximately 8hz. A vast majority of human technology seems to operate above that frequency. What might we have been picking up? From our research it appears that the magnetosphere could be capable of very long wavelengths such as that. Was it something arbitrary like that? Could it be some cosmological effect? Or is it something much more mundane and earth based which I am unaware of?

Any ideas? Am I reading this wrong? Is my meter just really inaccurate? Why would we see something so consistent if the meter was wrong? If I really was picking up such a long wave .... don't I need a much much much longer antenna?

Comment: Get a stopwatch, write down the values at fixed timings (say, every 10 seconds), and graph them (use graph paper for a hands on experience, [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) for experience making spreadsheet graphs). That way you can see if it's really a sine wave and rule out random drift.

Comment: If you can show it to be real, then I could imagine that some oscillation of the ionosphere or magnetosphere could have frequencies that low. You'd need to have a really big antenna to have something really sensitive to that frequency, though, so the odds are against it. See if the strength of the signal goes up or down with [solar activity](http://www.spaceweather.com/) (the kind that causes auroras).

Comment: I did it with the kids again this morning to see if the 'signal' was still there. Today it is oscillating with 12 second peaks and the voltage ranges from +000.9 to -001.0.

It is extremely consistent and most definitely doesn't jump around, it slowly ticks between every value. I don't have better equipment or I most certainly would take better measurements. It will consistently do this as long as I feel like sitting there watching. 

I wonder if I can write a small program for my raspberry pi to observe this but Im not sure it will naturally be sensitive enough to see that.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on setting up a Raspberry Pi to use an ADC: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-adc/
Also relevant to using an ADC as a voltmeter:
https://www.arduino-board.com/projects/arduino-voltmeter

Comment: You mention values like 001.2 which imply that the values you are measuring are very close to the minimum value your multimeter can detect. Unless this is an expensive, very accurate DMM, I suspect you are looking at random noise, or some internal activity in the DMM. Check the specs of your DMM for accuracy and resolution. What model are you using? What range is used to measure these mV  signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it isn't true that "the earth itself oscillates at approximately 8hz". I assume you're referring to [Schumann resonances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances), which are resonance frequencies of the Earth's atmosphere. These aren't oscillations of the Earth.

As for the oscillations you've measured, there are probably many possible explanations.

Assuming you only see this oscillation when you connect the multimeter to the dish (and not when the probes aren't connected to anything), one explanation that comes to mind is a phenomenon called [signal aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). Your multimeter barely has any bandwidth in DC voltage mode, and you're feeding it a very broad-band signal, so a relatively strong high-frequency signal could be masquerading in your multimeter as a very low frequency signal.

You can check if this is the case by putting together a simple LC or RC low-pass filter to attenuate frequencies higher than, say, 10Hz, and measuring with your multimeter the output of the filter (with the input connected to the dish).

Comment: This seems like the most logical explanation. Honestly, I figured there was something going on with the way the multimeter and the way it samples the data. Clearly there is a LOT more for me to learn about the way these things work. I appreciate the clear explanation and I am thinking you must be right.

Still fascinating.

Comment: It's a logical explanation, but not necessarily true. As I explained, it's easy to make sure this is really the explanation, by checking if the oscillation goes away when measuring through a low-pass filter.

Comment: All the more reason I accepted your answer. I am currently unable to test this but I will once I have the ability. 

Thank you.